# How do i loop through an array of objects in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, object, next.js

I want to loop through the array of objects in my `React` code.
I'm using `getStaticProps()` to fetch my data from an online fake `API` server.

I'm using `nextjs` for my code. How do I do this with `for` or `while` or any of the loops?

```js
import Head from 'next/head'


export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { todos: data }
    }
}
//the getStaticProps runs before the component is rendered, fetches the data and waits for the data and pumps it into the component so the component can be rendered with the data inside it.

const Todos = ({ todos }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>To Do List</title>
            </Head>
            <div>
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
                {todos.map(todoList => (
                    <div key={todoList.id}>
                        <a><h3> 
                        {  todoList.title}

                        </h3> </a>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Todos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
const Todos = ({ todos }) => {
return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <title>To Do List</title>
        </Head>
        <div>
            <h1>To Do List</h1>
            {todos && todos.length>0 && todos.map((todoList,index) => (
                {index < 50 && <div key={todoList.id}>
                    <a><h3> 
                    {  todoList.title}

                    </h3> </a>
                </div>}
            ))}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you must handle your array

```
    const Todos = ({ todos }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>To Do List</title>
            </Head>
            <div>
                <h1>To Do List</h1>
                {todos && todos.length>0 && todos.map(todoList => (
                    <div key={todoList.id}>
                        <a><h3> 
                        {  todoList.title}

                        </h3> </a>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: In my API, there are over 200 items. How do I make it so it only lists the first 50 items

Comment: you should use pagination to get other data from the server. and when get other data you add new data to old data

Comment: I don't understand